# Wordpress widget for post specific content in sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a wordpress plugin that will allow me to add a paragraph to the sidebar that is specific to the blog post. I would need to be able to add that text when creating the post. Is there something out there like that? I have been unsuccessful in searches.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something that I've ever personally done, but try this.

**Summary**: You will add the a paragraph using a custom field, then display it in a widget.

**Details**:

- First, make sure custom fields are enabled.  Edit a post, then click
  the "screen options" at the top right of the page.  If "Custom
  Fields" isn't checked, check it.  You should now see a custom field
  area below the post editor.
- Come up with a name for your custom field.  Perhaps
  "extra_paragraph".  Now put that in the "name" field in the custom
  field area.
- Write your paragraph in the "value" field the custom field area.
- Install the [Custom Field Widget plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-widget/), set it to display this
  new "extra_paragraph" field. (widget appears to be untested with newer versions of Wordpress so cross your fingers!)

Now when you write or edit posts you should see this "extra_paragraph" field as an option in the "name" dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily solved using Custom Fields, the Text Widget and a Shortcode.
This bit of code goes in the theme's `functions.php` or, preferable, within a [custom plugin](http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/).

**1) Enable shortcodes for the Text Widget**

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

**2) Define the shortcode, read comments for details**

```
add_shortcode( 'mytext', 'so_13735174_custom_text_widget' );

function so_13735174_custom_text_widget( $atts, $content = null )
{   
    global $post;

    // $post contains lots of info
    // Using $post->ID many more can be retrieved
    // Here, we are getting the Custom Field named "text"
    $html = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'text', true );

    // Custom Field not set or empty, print nothing
    if( !isset( $html ) || '' == $html )
        return '';

    // Print Custom Field
    return $html;
}
```

**3) Add a Text Widget in the desired sidebar.**
Leave the title empty and put the Shortcode in the content: `[mytext]`.

**4) Now each page or post with a Custom Field named `text` will have its value printed in the Widget.**

**5) The `$html` can get fancy and multiple Custom Fields can be used.**

Comment: Would something like this work for a Navigation TOC widget in the Left Sidebar?